# Puppeteer - Selecting Multiple Elements with CSS Selector within the Same Popup Div

Tags: css, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to select for example `2 Rooms and 3 Adults` on a hotel website (https://www.marriott.com/default.mi), but whichever CSS selector I code, my function either:

- My first Add Rooms code portion works and then the second Add Adults code portion adds to Rooms number as well (leading to 5 Rooms and default 1 Adults)
- My first Add Rooms code portion works and then the second Add Adults code portion returns `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')` (leading to 2 Rooms and then program returning Error).

e.g. Enter "Chicago, IL, USA" and select Aug 07 - Aug 10 for dates.

This is my async function code:

```
// Helper fx: Fill in number of rooms and number of guests (Room, Adult constants)
async function fill_room_and_guest(page, constants) {
  // Click drop-down menu for Room, Guest 
  await page.click('.search__rates.t-font-s[type="button"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('[class^="StyledPopupDiv"]');
  
  // Add Rooms - this adds the first element (Rooms)
  const add_rooms_icon = await page.$$('[class^="StyledPopupDiv"] .icon-plus:nth-of-type(1)');
  for (let i = 1; i < constants.NUM_ROOMS; i++) {
    // Press the "+" button in Rooms
    await add_rooms_icon[0].click();
  }

  //! Add Adults - NOT WORKING 
  // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')
  const add_adults_icon = await page.$$('[class^="StyledRowDiv"]:nth-of-type(2) > [class^="StyledIncrementDiv"] > .icon-plus');
  // const add_adults_icon = await page.$$('[class^="StyledPopupDiv"] .icon-plus:nth-of-type(2)');
  
  // Test:
  console.log(add_adults_icon); // sometimes returns empty array
  console.log(typeof add_adults_icon);

  for (let j = 1; j < constants.NUM_ADULTS; j++) {
    // Press the "+" button in Adults
    await add_adults_icon[0].click();
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `>` means "immediate child" but there's a button between the `StyledIncrementDiv` and the icon. Try removing all of your `>`s. 98% of the time, you don't need them--they're very rigid and restrictive. It's more than enough to say "get the `.icon-plus` anywhere in the `[class^="StyledIncrementDiv"]` subtree".

Comment: Removing the `>` worked! Thanks ggorlen@ :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Another nitpick: rather than `page.$$(...)[0]` you can use `page.$()`. Better yet, if it sometimes returns an empty array, use `const el = await page.waitForSelector(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer, the selector

```js
'[class^="StyledRowDiv"]:nth-of-type(2) > [class^="StyledIncrementDiv"] > .icon-plus'
```

is too rigid. There's a `<button>` in between `StyledIncrementDiv` and `.icon-plus`, but `>` only looks inside immediate children. Remove it to search the whole subtree.

In general, avoid `>` unless it's necessary to disambiguate something like:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <span>I want this element</span>
    <span>I want this element</span>
    <div>
      <span>But not this element</span>
      <span>But not this element</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a weird edge case where `.wrapper > div > span` is useful for avoiding the nested elements that `.wrapper span` would match. But this doesn't show up much. 98% of the time, avoid `>`.

---

Also, `page.$$()` selects multiple elements, so if you just want the first one, prefer `page.$()`. If that element isn't showing up consistently, use `const el = await page.waitForSelector(...)` instead. If this is failing, check the selector or examine the page's dynamic behavior to figure out what the actual conditions are to make it appear.